# Chrome showing "bullet" with each item in top menu

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, navigation

I have been trying to solve this problem for more than 2 hours now but no luck. I have a top menu (based on UL/LI) which displays fine in IE and Firefox but on Chrome it is showing "bullet" besides each item. Please check the following screenshot, you will see bullet on left side with LINK1, LINK2 and LINK3.

[image]

What I have been able to ascertain so far that I need to add some code in CSS to remove this and not DELETE code from CSS because I deleted all relevant code from CSS but these bullets were still showing so may be I need to write some property which will override and won't show these bullets in Chrome!?

Comment: Post some relevant piece of code.

Comment: I wanted to but the code is too long and it will have lots of irrelevant code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would be helpful but for starters:

```
ul, ul li{list-style:none;}
```

Comment: This ALMOST solved my problem. When I applied it did remove that bullet but it also removed it from left menu which I am displaying. Is there a code I can write in left menu so it should continue to show what it is showing? I tried writing "!important" but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok I changed the code to "ul {list-style:none;}" and it fixed the problem. Thanks.